# how to join second and third table together in eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

i have three model 1.Document 2.Sharedoc   3.User

Document.php

```
class Document extends Model
{
    public function sharedoc(){

        return $this->hasMany('App\Sharedoc','docId','id'); 

    }

    public function user(){

        return $this->belongsTo('App\User','userId','id');
    }
}
```

Sharedoc.php

```
class Sharedoc extends Model
{
    public function document(){

        return $this->belongsTo('App\Document','docId','id'); 

    }
}
```

User.php

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
public function document(){

        return $this->hasMany('App\Document','userId','id'); 

    }
}
```

controller:

```
$data = Document::with('sharedoc','user')
           ->where('userid',Auth::user()->id)
           ->orderBy('id','DESC')
           ->get();
return $data;
```

Result is:

```
10  
    id  21
    name:   " 20190121083621.txt"
    userId: 3
    type:   "txt"
    size:   0
    created_at: "2019-01-21 08:36:21"
    updated_at: "2019-01-21 08:36:21"
    sharedoc:   
         0: 
             id:    9
             docId: 21
             fromUserId:    3
             toUserId:  6
             created_at:    "2019-01-22 15:34:50"
             updated_at:    "2019-01-22 15:34:50"
        1   
             id:    8
             docId: 21
             fromUserId:    3
             toUserId:  5
             created_at:    "2019-01-21 09:32:39"
             updated_at:    "2019-01-21 09:32:39"
    user:   
        id: 3
        name:   "تست تست"
        email:  "f.ghorbani@gmail.com"
        active: 1
        isClickActiveLink:  1
        isSendMail: 1
        isAdmin:    1
        created_at: "2019-01-20 15:53:29"
        updated_at: "2019-01-20 16:37:32"
```

In this result ‘document’ table join with ‘sharedoc’ and ‘user’ tables… but I want ‘document’ join with ‘sharedoc’ and then ‘sharedoc’ join with ‘user’…
how i can do it?

Comment: does `sharedocs` table have a foreign key with `users` table? if yes, create a relationship with it and then call `Document::with('sharedoc','sharedoc.name_of_the_new_relationship')`

Comment: Perfect! Helped a lot man :)Thanks a lot.

Comment: ^^ glad it works